# Renderer process of electron is crashed when program use C++ Native Addon And gl gl.texImage2D in WebGL

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I make the variable of Uint8Array in C++ Native Addon.

C++ Native Addon is maked by node-gyp and napi.

However, Renderer process of electron is crashed when I use the variable as texture in WebGL.

Why is that? Is this a bug in Electron's WebGL?

Source Code in C++ Native Addon.

```
#include <napi.h>

int width=800;
int height=600;
uint8_t* foo;

Napi::TypedArrayOf<uint8_t> get(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info ) 
{
    buf = Napi::ArrayBuffer::New(info.Env(),foo,4*width*height);
    ret = Napi::TypedArrayOf<uint8_t>::New(info.Env(),
                                          4*width*height,
                                          buf,
                                          0);
    return ret;
}


Napi::Object init( Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports ) 
{
    foo=new uint8_t[4*width*height]; 
    exports.Set( Napi::String::New( env, "get" ), Napi::Function::New( env, get ) );
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE( addon, init )
```

The parts of Source Code in JavaScript

```
function draw() {
   var texWidth=800;
   var texHeight=600;
   gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   
   //get variable of Uint8Array from C++ Native Addon
   pixels = myaddon.get();
   texture = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   //Crash here
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

   gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   gl.useProgram(program);
   gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   gl.uniform1i(uniforms['u_texture'], 0);
   gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurs when the C++ code encounters an unhandled exception.

Where did you declare buf and ret?

Also try allocating space for foo before using it.

```
uint8_t* foo = new uint8_t[4*width*height];
```